# Can not find TimeStamp

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

in my Azure project with TableStorage I get the following Exception:

*Run-Time Error in Microsoft JScript: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: A field or property with name 'TimeStamp' was not found in the selected data source*

The original german message is:

*Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft JScript: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Feld oder Eigenschaft mit dem Namen TimeStamp wurde nicht in der ausgewählten Datenquelle gefunden.*

I always get this if I try to access the TableStorage. The code is for example

```
storageAccount = GlobalStorageAccount.GetGlobalStorageAccount();
storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist(tableName);
```

The class GlobalStorageAccount:

```
public class GlobalStorageAccount
{
    private static CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;

    public static CloudStorageAccount GetGlobalStorageAccount()
    {
        if (_storageAccount == null)
        {
            var acc = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("...", "...");
            _storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(acc, true);
        }
        return _storageAccount;
    }
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you get an error? Is it when you're trying to fetch entities from the table? or just when you're trying to create table?

Comment: Both. By the way, I also get the error when I delete the table and call CreateTableIfNotExist().

Comment: One reason I could think of is name of "TimeStamp". The attribute in an entity is actually named "Timestamp" (notice small "s"). That's the reason I asked if you're getting error when fetching entities.